# Title in toolbar issue

Tags: android-toolbar, titlebar

the title of my toolbar i took it from the data base inside the fragment with this code:

```
 JSONObject response = new JSONObject(responseObj.body().string());
                        if (response.getBoolean("success")) {
                            responseData = response.getJSONObject("data");
                            HomeActivity.checkLoading = false;

                            getActivity().setTitle(response.getJSONObject("data").getString("page_title"));
```

and now after i used hide fragment while i´m switching fragments , the title keep the same while i´m going back.

how can i refresh just the title and took it back from the database without refreshing the whole fragment ?

thanks